# Resize Array Template

Tags: c++

I need a template Function to resize an Array of any type.

My try:

```
class CCommon
{
template < typename T >
static void ResizeArray(T* paArray, int iOldSize, int iNewSize, T tInitValue);
}

..

template < typename T >
void CCommon::ResizeArray(T* paArray, int iOldSize, int iNewSize, T tInitValue)
{
   T* paTmpArray = new T[iOldSize];
   for(int i = 0; i < iOldSize; i++)
   {
      paTmpArray[i] = paArray[i];
   }
   delete [] paArray;
   paArray=new T[iNewSize];
   for(int i=0; i < iNewSize; i++)
   {
      paArray[i] = tInitValue;
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < iOldSize; i++)
   {
      paArray[i] = paTmpArray[i];
   }
   delete [] paTmpArray;
}
```

The CCommon File is compilable, but I get an
"unresolved external references" error:

> `Fehler 2 error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: static void __cdecl CCommon::ResizeArray<int>(int*,int,int,int)" (??$ResizeArray@H@CCommon@@SAXPAHHHH@Z)" in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall CWaebi_OBJ::ReInit(void)" (?ReInit@CWaebi_OBJ@@QAEXXZ)". CWaebi_OBJ.obj`
>
> `Fehler 3 fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste externe Verweise. c:\PolFlow\Debug\Balance_V1.exe 1`

How I want to call it:

```
#include CCommon

SomeFunction
{
..
CCommon::ResizeArray<BOOL>( mTextIndexMask, m_iNumberOfLastTextMaskArray, mTextCount, FALSE );
..
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Most SO users won't be able to read the error messages.

Comment: “unresolved external references”.

Comment: And yet another template definition in a .cpp file.

Comment: You probably want to pass the pointer by reference --not related to the question, but a bug none-the-less--. Also your function is costly (you are copying more than you need) and not exception-safe in any way.

Comment: @Donotalo: "Verweis auf nicht..." is German; "??$ResizeArray@H@CCommon@@SAXPAHHHH@Z" is the binary language of moisture vaporators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template < typename T >
void CCommon::ResizeArray(T* paArray, int iOldSize, int iNewSize, T tInitValue)
{
 T* paTmpArray = new T[iOldSize];
 for(int i = 0; i < iOldSize; i++)
 {
  paTmpArray[i] = paArray[i];
 }
 delete [] paArray;
 paArray=new T[iNewSize];
 for(int i=0; i < iNewSize; i++)
 {
  paArray[i] = tInitValue;
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < iOldSize; i++)
 {
  paArray[i] = paTmpArray[i];
 }
 delete [] paTmpArray;
}
```

That's not going to work. After call to that function value of paArray will not be changed. You'll get a memory leak, plus paArray will be pointing to garbage after that call. 
Also, you don't need to make it a static class function. Using template function is enough.
And you don't need temporary array.

Use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T> void resizeArray(T*& arr, int oldSize, int newSize, const T initVal){
    T* newArray = new T[newSize];

    for (int i = 0; (i < oldSize)&&(i<newSize); i++)
        newArray[i] = arr[i];

    for (int i = oldSize; i < newSize; i++)
        newArray[i] = initVal;

    delete[] arr;
    arr = newArray;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    const int startSize = 26, newSize = 42;
    int* p = new int[startSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < startSize; i++)
        p[i] = i;

    resizeArray(p, startSize, newSize, 87);

    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

or this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T> void resizeArray(T*& arr, int oldSize, int newSize, const T initVal){
    T* newArray = new T[newSize];

    std::copy(arr, arr+std::min(oldSize, newSize), newArray);

    if (oldSize < newSize)
        std::fill(newArray+oldSize, newArray+newSize, initVal);

    delete[] arr;
    arr = newArray;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    const int startSize = 26, newSize = 42;
    int* p = new int[startSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < startSize; i++)
        p[i] = i;

    resizeArray(p, startSize, newSize, 87);

    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

instead.

Comment: Still not exception safe (use `auto_ptr` for new array, then release it after all copies succeed).  Well, obviously not `auto_ptr`, which can't deal with arrays, but an array version of it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, why on Earth are you using some custom `BOOL` type instead of C++'s built-in `bool`?

Secondly, it sounds like you have placed the template implementation in a source file. Is the implementation of `CCommon::ResizeArray` in the ccommon.h file that you are including in the where you call it? If not, put it there (or in a file included by it). Templates need to have their entire implementation in header files to work. You can't have the declaration in the header and the definition in a source file like with normal functions and methods.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to define your template member function in a .cpp file.
This is bad. Templates depends on types resolved at instantiation time, having the full definition to produce correct code.
Solution: put your definition in a .hxx file, included by your .h .

Answer (score 1):

Once you've fixed the template in cpp problem (@Tyler McHenry), your ResizeArray still won't work, because you're never returning your newly allocated array to the caller.
Either you have to return it, or take in a T** as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you try to put the implementation in the *.cpp file. Templates have to be implemented in the header.

Another point is the fact that your code has a major bug in it:
You don't return the new pointer at all, you only overwrite the local copy of your parameter.
This means that the newly allocated memory is leaked and any code trying to access the array afterwards will probably crash.

Oh and another tip: why exactly are you copying your array contents into a temporary variable? you could just allocate an array of the new size, copy the contents into that one, delete the old array and either return the new pointer or make pArray a T** and assign the new arraypointer to that one.

As a last point I would suggest using the `std::copy` and `std::fill` operations for copying /filling the array contents, e.g.:
instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i < iOldSize; i++)
{
    paTmpArray[i] = paArray[i];
}
```

use

```
std::copy(paArray, paArray+iOldSize, paTmpArray);
```

It leads to less and more consise code and is probably more optimized then doing it in a loop.

So here is how i would suggest to do this:

```
#include <algorithm>
template < typename T >
void CCommon::ResizeArray(T*& paArray, int iOldSize, int iNewSize, T tInitValue)
{
 T* paTmpArray = new T[iNewSize];
 std::copy(paArray, paArray + std::min(iNewSize, iOldSize), paTmpArray);
 delete[] paArray;
 if(iNewSize > iOldSize)
     std::fill(paTmpArray + iOldSize, paTmpArray + iNewSize, tInitValue);
 paArray = paTmpArray;
}
```

Comment: like this?


BOOL* tmpTextIndexMask = new BOOL[iNewSize];

for(int i=0; i<iOldSize; i++)
{
 tmpTextIndexMask[i] = mTextIndexMask[i];
}
mTextIndexMask = tmpTextIndexMask;

Comment: "std::copy(paTmpArray, paTmpArray+iOldSize, paArray);" Will crash if new size is smaller than old size.

Comment: if your mTextIndexMask is a BOOL** (and you use *mTextIndexMask =..) or a BOOL*& then yes. Otherwise you still have the bug that you don't return your value.